# How to create a Google::Protobuf::Map Instance [Ruby]

Tags: ruby, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf object in ruby, and it has a map as one parameter. How can I create a `Google::Protobuf::Map`? If I try to enter a standard hash table, I get an `Expected Map instance` error.

**--EDIT--**

Found the answer here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/ruby-generated#map-fields, if anyone needs that.